# ajax with php mailer error: 404

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer, mailer

I have set up an ajax call on a form to send a post event to my php mailer script. However, the post goes to the url /undefined rather than mailer.php and the error 'The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server.' with code 404 is returned. Here is the ajax script:

```
$("#contactForm").on("submit", function (event) {
  if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
    formError();
    submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm();
  }
});


function submitForm(){
  // Initiate Variables With Form Content
  var email = $("#email").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mailer.php",
    data: "email=" + email,
    complete : function(text){
      if (text == "success"){
        console.log(text);
        formSuccess();
      } else {
        formError();
        submitMSG(false,text);
      }
    }
  });
}

function formSuccess(){
  $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
  submitMSG(true, "Awesome! We'll be in touch.")
}

function formError(){
  $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass();
  });
}
```

I have placed my PHP script in the same folder, but there seems to be an error finding the php script.

```
<?php
    // My modifications to mailer script from:
    // http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "test@test.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "Hello";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content .= "hello";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <test@test.com>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            // http_response_code(200);
            echo "success";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            // http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

I also have a .htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

```
# redirect html pages to the root domain
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]

# remove trailing html on routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Make sure you check your filepaths. For example, if the form is in ```http://yoursite.com/forms/email.html```, but your emailer is in ```http://yoursite.com/emailer.emailer.php```, then you'll need to change your ajax url to ```../emailer/emailer.php```

Comment: all the files are in the same folder, would a .htaccess script effect anything?

Comment: It's possible the htaccess file could be redirecting your POST requests

Comment: check apache error log

Comment: I have added my .htaccess file to the question.

Comment: Disable your .htaccess rewrites and then test the form. If it works, then you'll need to ignore POST requests in your htaccess file

Comment: I have disabled it however am experiencing the same error

Comment: it seems to be routing to a /undefined url rather than the mailer